# How to access the Contacts Folder in Lotus Notes Using Lotus Notes Java API

Tags: java, lotus-notes

My requirement is to get the All the Contact details od one user from Lotus Notes. I am using Notes API. I want the code sample for getting contact details.

Comment: Ya I agree All the Answers are useful to me... I don't know how to accept... But I chose yes option for was this post useful to you?... Can you please tell me how to accept the answers

Comment: I need the above requirement soon. Please anybody help me...

Comment: Can you clarify if you mean contact details or contacts folder?(view?). For starting off the infocenter help has code samples which you can modify as needed.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question.  Please clarify which of these is your problem:  1.  You want to read all the information for all of the entries in one Notes user's contacts list in the Notes client or iNotes (Domino Web Access).  2. You have the name of a Lotus Notes user and you want to read the contact information from that user from the Domino Directory. 3. Something else?

Comment: Hi Simon, I Want the contacts in the Contact Folder... I am not able to find the code samples... can you please send the link?

Comment: Hi rhsatrhs, The Second one is I need.. I have the user id for that particular retrieve the contact information from the contact folder...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of my head...

```
Database db = session.getDatabase("names.nsf");
NotesViewEntryCollection nvec = db.getView("People").getAllEntries();
for(int i=0;i<nvec.getCount();i++){
    doc = nvec.getNthEntry(i).getDocument();
    // get value of doc here
    // recycle
}
```

Comment: Is that only way to use names.nsf file to get the contacts... Instead of that there is an nsf file which will be created in the username (Like my user name is anand, so anand.nsf file will be created). Is there anyway to extract the contacts for that user  using that user nsf file?